# How to get size of a list(returning from Controller) in onChange() JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

I am returning a list from Controller class.

```
httpReq.setAttribute("playersList", playersList);
```

I want size of this list in onchange() method.

```
$('#teams').on('change', function(){
 // code to get the size/count
  if(count < 11){
  .........
  }else{
  .........
  }
}
```

here I am displaying that list:

```
<tr id = "players" style="display:none;">
    <td class="tabHead">PLAYER NAMES</td>
    <td>
        <div class=""  id="playerNames" name="playerNames" >            
            <c:forEach items="${playersList}" var="playersListItem">                                
                ${playersListItem.name}<br> 
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
    </td>       
</tr>
```

I tried -

```
var count = playersList.length;
var count = $("#players").length;
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: "httpReq.setAttribute("playersList", playersList);" to which language this belong? i.e. what is your serverside ?

Comment: @ A.T. spring mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that each item in your list is some unformatted text followed by a `<br>` element:

```
${playersListItem.name}<br>
```

...all within a particular `<div>` within a particular `<tr>`. So to count them **just count the `<br>` elements** that are inside the `<tr>` or `<div>` using one of the following:

```
var count = $("#players").find("br").length;
var count = $("#players br").length;
var count = $("#playerNames").find("br").length;
var count = $("#playerNames br").length;
```

(Note that the second thing you tried, `$("#players").length`, should always return either 0 or 1, because selecting by element id should always find either 0 or 1 element.)

Comment: yes , $("#players").length was giving always 1. great Solution . Worked . thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a tribute selector

```
$("[id='players'] br").length;
```

or

```
$('#playerNames > *').length;
```

Comment: thank you so much. I tried -  $("[id='players'] br").length; worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you change your table structure a little, you can easily find the count. Like here I add class 'playerName' and count it inside the players TR tag

```
<tr id="players" style="display:none;">
    <td class="tabHead">PLAYER NAMES</td>
    <td>
        <div id="playerNames" name="playerNames" >            
            <c:forEach items="${playersList}" var="playersListItem">                                
                <div class="playerName">${playersListItem.name}</div> 
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
    </td>       
</tr>


$('#players .playerName').length
```

Comment: I tried this one also but it gives 0. Anyway .. thank you so much.